# Removing query string from a view in Django

Tags: javascript, python, django, python-3.x

I have a page called controlpanel, where I can start/stop scripts. When the button for start and stop scripts is pressed, it return the same page with button color changed and I want to delete query string.

**view.py**

```py
def controlpanel(request):
   data = {'paypal': paypal_, 'cpu': cpu_usage, 'active': active_task ...}
   return render(request, 'admin/controlpanel.html', context=data) 

def startapp(request):
    if request.META['QUERY_STRING']:
        #... start scripts etc..
        request.META['QUERY_STRING'] = False

        return controlpanel(request)
```

the function return controlpanel with query string... (127.0.0.1:8000/startapp?run=True but I only want 127.0.0.1:8000/controlpanel)

**controlpanel.html**

```html
<div>
{% if active %}
 <button onclick="f()" class="btn btn-md btn-success">Start</button>
{% else %}
 <button onclick="f()" class="btn btn-md btn-warning">Start</button>
{% endif %}
</div>


<script>
function f() {
let a = null;
if ('{{active}}' === 'True') {
  a = 'stop'
} else {
  a = 'start'
}
window.location.href = "/startapp?run=" + a;            
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Django's [redirect](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) to return the URL without the query parameters.